# parse text file with array in java

Tags: java

I have to parse a text file with array of string the code bellow work fine I need a support how to get rid of the header of fields ( G1 & G2 & G3)  while parsing the text file .

```
   try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Test.txt"))) {               
               
                 String N=null;
                 
                while( scan.hasNextLine() )
                {
                    //scan.skip(Pattern.compile("G1  G2  G3 "));
                    
                    String[] ary = scan.nextLine().split( "\\s+" );           
                    
                    if( ary.length == 3)
                    {
                        if( ary[0].startsWith( "A-" ) )
                            
                            N = ary[0]; 

             System.out.printf( "A-%-5s %5s %5s%n", N, ary[1], ary[2] );
```

2/  file sample is :

```
START

ELEMENT

G1      G2      G3
A-0     FX      0
        FX      1 
A-20    FY      0
        FY      1
```

thanks

Comment: your code should work, what's wrong with the scanner skip method you commented ? it should do exactly what you wanted

Comment: with this the header is printed System.out.println("get=:" + N + ",mget="+ary[1]+",mget="+ary[2]); I want to get rid of G1 & G2 & G3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works principally, but I assume you are looking for something easier.

Really useful are `Stream`s and the utility class `Files`, operating of the class `Path`, a more general concept of `File`.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Test.txt");

// Data of A-* F* 0:
List<String[]> data = Files.lines(path) // lines(path, charset)
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(arr -> arr.length == 3)
            .filter(arr -> arr[0].startsWith("A-"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For just printing:

```
    Files.lines(path, Charset.forName("Windows-1252"))
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
                    .filter(arr -> arr.length == 3)
                    .filter(arr -> arr[0].startsWith("A-"))
                    .forEach(arr -> System.out.printf("%-7s %5s %5s%n",
                            arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]));
```

If the problem is the grouping by G1 (empty first column as repetition), a no-brainer would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/Develop/Test.txt");
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicReference<String> g1 = new AtomicReference<>("");
    Files.lines(path) // UTF-8 file
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
                    .filter(arr -> arr.length == 3)
                    .filter(arr -> arr[0].startsWith("A-")
                            || (arr[0].isEmpty() && !data.isEmpty()))
                    .forEach(arr -> {
                        if (!arr[0].isEmpty()) {
                            g1.set(arr[0]);
                        }
                        System.out.printf("%-7s %5s %5s%n", g1, arr[1], arr[2]);
                        arr[0] = g1.get();
                        data.add(arr);
                    });
    for (String[] ary : data) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
    }
}
```

I think the latter is what you intended with `N`.
To receive

```
A-0     FX      0
A-0     FX      1 
A-20    FY      0
A-20    FY      1
```

Comment: @ Joop:
I want to use ArrayList<JButton> adding Action listeners with ArrayList .
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {   
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Test.txt");
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
I have got following error :
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String[]>

Comment: The you imported `java.awt.List`, an old GUI list component. Instead use `java.util.List`. Success

Comment: thanks Joop error has gone ,  but I still have some error can you edit the whole program 'im using java 8 IDE eclipse 
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation

Comment: The last section?

Comment: Corrected all the code. The java language level must be set to java 8 if the code still does not compile. I had i.a. a missing closing quote `"`.

Comment: I have another question but I prefer to start  a new thread with title :merge two text file and parse them with array java.thanks